# What results is the box plot showing when I just pass the entire dataframe with no x, y, data parameters?

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

I am learning visualisation using python libraries. I was playing around with the in-built "tips" dataset. I noticed that the seaborn plots the data even when I don't give any parameters like x = , y= , data =. This is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
tips_data = sns.load_dataset("tips")
tips_data.head()
sns.boxplot(tips_data.iloc[:,[0,1]])
sns.boxplot(data=tips_data.iloc[:,[0,1]])
```

If you run these commands, you will notice that the first boxplot command plots a single box plot which is not same as the box plot for either columns, their mean or their sum.

The second box plot command correctly, plots two box plots on the same axes - one for tips and another for total_bill.

Can someone please tell what exactly is being plotted when no parameter arg is specified?

I tried checking out the seaborn documentation [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html)! but didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1**

`sns.boxplot(tips_data.iloc[:,[0,1]])` is equivalent to

```
sns.boxplot(x=tips_data.iloc[:,[0,1]])
```

namely, that the first argument is `x`. This is interpreted as all the data in the input are to be distributed along the x axis. More understandably, one might this as the flattened 2D array from the two columns,

```
sns.boxplot(x=tips_data.iloc[:,[0,1]].values.flatten())
```

**Case 2**

If instead using `sns.boxplot(data=tips_data.iloc[:,[0,1]])`, no `x` and `y` are given. Hence they need to be interpreted, which is done columnwise. You will then get one boxplot per column.

---

The documentation states:

> Input data can be passed in a variety of formats, including:
>
> - Vectors of data represented as lists, numpy arrays, or pandas Series objects passed directly to the x, y, and/or hue parameters. **[Case 1]**
> - A “long-form” DataFrame, in which case the x, y, and hue variables will determine how the data are plotted.
> - A “wide-form” DataFrame, such that each numeric column will be plotted.
>     An array or list of vectors. **[Case 2]**

I marked the two cases from the question in the documentation.